# Adding Attribute to base control of custom control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have created a custom control which is a numeric textbox which inherits a textbox control.
But when it renders , the source of page show me 2 textboxes - one with id of custom control and other one with customcontrol's id and appended with _txt_ctrl.

I want that this base control (with _txt_ctrl) should not render. 
In case if we cant do it, atleast and can add attribute to my base control. 
I tried this line but of no use.

```
base.Attributes.Add("Title", "This is a Numeric Textbox, only accepts numbers.");
```

![Error ScreenShot -  Additional Textbox][1]

```
  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write("<Table id=" + this.ClientID + "_tbl" + " width='100%' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' border='0'><TR><TD>");
            base.Render(writer);
            writer.Write("</TD></TR></Table>");
        }
```

and init

```
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("NumericTextBoxScript") == false)
            {
                string _strScriptSrc = Page.Request.ApplicationPath + "/CommonFramework/Presentation/JavaScripts/FACESNumericTextBox.js";

                string strScriptBlock = "<script src='"
                    + _strScriptSrc
                    + "'></script>";

                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "NumericTextBoxScript", strScriptBlock);
            }

            this.RegisterClientScriptFunction();

            // Adding the TextAlign property to the control's stylesheet.            
            if (this.TextAlign != null && this.TextAlign != String.Empty)
                this.Style.Add("text-align", this.TextAlign);

            this.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "OnKeyPress_NumericEdit(event,'" + this.ClientID + "');");
            this.Attributes.Add("onblur", "FormatInteger_NumericEdit('" + this.ClientID + "');");
            this.Attributes.Add("MaxValue", _maxValue.ToString());
            this.Attributes.Add("MinValue", _minValue.ToString());
            this.Attributes.Add("MinDecimalPlaces", Convert.ToInt32(_minDecimalPlaces).ToString());
            this.Attributes.Add("DataMode", Convert.ToInt32(_dataMode).ToString());
            this.Attributes.Add("IsMaxValueSet", IsMaxValueSet.ToString());
            this.Attributes.Add("IsMinValueSet", IsMinValueSet.ToString());
            this.Attributes.Add("ValueChange", _valueChange);
        this.Attributes.Add("Title", "This is a Numeric Textbox, only accepts numbers.");
base.Attributes.Add("Title", "This is a Numeric Textbox, only accepts numbers.");


        }
```

Comment: Can you show use the code of your custom control?

Comment: Your screenshot link is broken, please fix it.

Comment: Trinimon : Site is not allowing me to upload the image :(